# Applescript: How to move a file after finishing processing it?

Tags: finder, applescript, macos, file

I'm very new to writing applescript, but have been painfully working through it.

I have successfully written scripts to download specific csv attachments from an email inbox, then create an SQL insert statement from them. I'm now trying add a statement to move the original file to an archive folder so the SQL insert script does not act on those files the next time it runs. The variable"DEP_name" is the name of the file captured earlier in the script:

```
        tell application "Finder"
            set orgpath to "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Documents:source_folder:" as string
            set originalFolder to (orgpath & DEP_name) as string

            set newpath to "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Documents:Archive:" as string
            set newFolder to (newpath & DEP_name) as string

            move originalFolder to newFolder with replacing
        end tell
```

With this version I get the error: "Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." I have also tried using the Posix file path, but I am getting a different error with that attempt. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the second to last line to:

```
move alias originalFolder to alias newpath with replacing
```

There are two things:

1. All four variables are just strings. In order to tell Finder that they are related to the filesystem, add `alias` (or `file` or `folder`) before the string.
2. The path where are are moving it to should be the path of the enclosing folder, not the path of the moved folder in its new location.